# Referencing part of a book that's by multiple authors, but not in an edited collection

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I need to add a bibliographic reference to a section of a book in bibtex, which is a paper with its own title, by a single author, but in a book that's written by four authors, and not an edited collection.

In an edited collection, I would use @incollection, and put down the author of the paper, and the editor of the collection.  But in this case, the book has four authors and no editor.  It's a collaboration in which each author has written a separate paper, and then a separate response to the other authors.  This means I need a separate field for the book authors (which needs to contain all four names), and for the paper author (which needs to contain just the author who wrote this particular paper).

I can't use @inbook, since this only has one author field, for the book as a whole.  If I put put in all four book author names, it looks as if I am mean to imply that the claims I am citing are endorsed by all of them, and that would be misleading.  If I only put the name of the author who wrote the particular chapter I want to cite, it gives the impression that one author wrote the whole book, failing to credit the others for their roles in authoring the book.

And I can't use @incollection, because this means I either have to ignore the other authors completely, and leave the editor field blank (which again fails to credit the other authors for their part in the book), or else I would have to put the other authors (misleadingly) in the editor field (they did not edit the collection, they authored the other parts of the book, which is not the same thing).  I couldn't put all four names in the author field, since this would once again give the impression that the claims I am attributing to one author are equally endorsed by the others, and that would be misleading too.

Is there any way to add a separate field for book authors and chapter authors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider to use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) -- with this package, `@inbook` is used for *"[a] part of a book which forms a self-contained unit with its own title. Note that the profile
of this entry type is different from standard BibTeX"* (manual, section 2.1.1).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[maxnames=99]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {A paper with its own title, by a single author},
  bookauthor = {Author, A., and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C. and Duthor, D.},
  booktitle = {A book that's written by four authors},
  location = {A location},
  publisher = {A publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this is a go, it looks like exactly what I need!